# Place rows of all columns behind each other based on values in one column

Tags: r, rows, bind

I'm having trouble finding a correct way to combine rows. I have the following dataframe:

```
Donornr    Final_location_DF.Location Final_location_DF.Date Familynr    Date_T4 Sample_volume_T4
1  449023 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A1             24/11/2020       13 24/11/2020               50
2  449027 84278_V113_top shelf_doos1_A1             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300
3  449027 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A2             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300
4  449028 84278_V113_top shelf_doos1_A2             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300
5  449028 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A3             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300
```

As you can see, in the column Donornr we have duplicate numbers but the row values are not all the same (mainly in the Final_location_DF.location column). What I need is to place the duplicate donornumbers behind each other so that I will end up with:

```
      Donornr    Final_location_DF.Location Final_location_DF.Date Familynr    Date_T4 Sample_volume_T4
        1  449023 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A1             24/11/2020       13 24/11/2020               50
        2  449027 84278_V113_top shelf_doos1_A1             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300   449027 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A2             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300 
        3  449028 84278_V113_top shelf_doos1_A2             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300   449028 84278_V113_top shelf_blok1_A3             24/11/2020       12 24/11/2020              300
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: This can be done by reshaping/pivoting your data from long to wide format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below creates an 'id' column that is used to distinguish cases within the same `Donornr`, then turns the data frame into wide form. The column names will be the original column names, with `_{id}` appended. The last step sorts the columns in the order you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Donornr) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Donornr,
              names_from = id,
              values_from = Final_location_DF.Location:Sample_volume_T4) %>%
  select(Donornr, ends_with("_1"), everything())
```